# What is this "upside-down T" notation: $S^\perp$

Tags: real-analysis, notation

In this screenshot, I want to know that the upside-down T is. (I'm not sure how to research it if I don't know its name) =)

[image: Screenshot]

(The context, is to prove that that $(S^{\perp})^{\perp}$ is the smallest closed subset of $H$ contained in $S$, where $S$ is a subspace of a Hilbert space $H$).  But I just want to know the notation.

Comment: orthogonal complement

Comment: The $\LaTeX$/MathJax command is `\perp`.

Comment: Useful link: [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).  You can draw the symbol and it will give you some possible macros to match.

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to the orthogonal complement of a given subspace. So, $S^{\perp}$ is the orthogonal complement of $S$ and $(S^{\perp})^{\perp}$ is the orthogonal complement of $S^{\perp}$.